# Zooming in/out on subplots in Octave

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I have created six subplots on one page in Octave as shown in the image below:

[image: Attempt to zoom in on first subplot]

When I try to zoom in on say the first subplot, it instead zooms in on the last subplot (row 3, col 2); it zooms in way in the negative part of the x-axis. I think I know what it depends on because [GNU Octave docs state](https://docs.octave.org/latest/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html): "*the next call to subplot activates the second subplot area, but does not re-partition the figure*."

However, I don't know how to fix this. Is there anyway to focus on other subplots either code-wise or using the window-tools?